# How to pass list from view to controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, list, asp.net-mvc-4

I have problem when pass a list in an object from view to controller, the list is always null. How should I do this?

My model:

```
public class ImageModel
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
    public bool delete { get; set; }
}

public class SchoolImages
{
    public Nullable<int> schoolid { get; set; }
    public IList<ImageModel> images;
}
```

The view:

```
@model SchoolAppManager.Models.SchoolImages

@using (Html.BeginForm("DeleteImages", "Images"))
{

    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.schoolid)
    <table>
    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.images.Count(); i += 4) {

        <tr>
            <td>
                <img src="@Url.Content(Model.images[i].url)" width="50%" />
                <br />
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.images[i].delete)
                @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.images[i].id)
            </td>
            <td>
                @if (i + 1 < Model.images.Count())
                {
                    <img src="@Url.Content(Model.images[i + 1].url)" width="50%" />
                    <br />
                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.images[i + 1].delete)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.images[i + 1].id)
                }
            </td>
            <td>
                @if (i + 2 < Model.images.Count())
                {
                    <img src="@Url.Content(Model.images[i + 2].url)" width="50%" />
                    <br />
                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.images[i + 2].delete)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.images[i + 2].id)
                }
            </td>
            <td>
                @if (i + 3 < Model.images.Count())
                {
                    <img src="@Url.Content(Model.images[i + 3].url)" width="50%" />
                    <br />
                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.images[i + 3].delete)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.images[i + 3].id)
                }
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
    </table>

    <input type="submit" value="delete" />
}
```

When I click delete, `SchoolImages` is passed to the controller, `SchoolImages.schoolId` has value in the controller, however, `SchoolImages.images` is null. How can I pass `SchoolImages.images` to controller?

Comment: the only way I know of to pass a list to the controller is build it with jquery and pass it through an ajax call.  If possible it would be a lot easier to pass an id and recreate the list on the controller

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Default model binder doesn't work with fields, so make `images` a property:

```
public IList<ImageModel> images { get; set; }
```

Comment: what a stupid mistake, thank you @Zabavsky, you save me a lot of time!

Answer (score 1):

I guess you will have problem binding complex types to your model. In case you don't get that working. Here is the alternative way.

You have a bunch of checkboxes, possibly with the same name and different values. You could post them to a method that takes a FormCollection, ie.

```
public ActionResult Test(FormCollection collection)
{
    string results = collection["Blanks"];
}
```

This would give you a comma-delimited list of values (or null, where no checkboxes are ticked).

Alternatively, if you have the possible values as an array on the server then you could give the checkboxes names according to their array values, which would mean you could do something like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Test","Home"))
{
    @Html.CheckBox("Blanks[0]", false);
    @Html.CheckBox("Blanks[1]", false);
    @Html.CheckBox("Blanks[2]", false);

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
}
```

giving you an array of booleans in your Test method:

public ActionResult Test(bool[] Blanks)
{        }

Comment: thanks, your method is very useful, however, @Zabavsky's answer did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your model "SchoolImages"; use array instead of IList<>.

Answer (score 0):

It's null because the default model binder doesn't know how to initialize it.
Change your field images to be a property and add a constructor like this:

```
public class SchoolImages
{
    public SchoolImages()
    {
        images = new List<ImageModel>();
    }
    public Nullable<int> schoolid { get; set; }
    public IList<ImageModel> images { get; set; }
}
```

It should work.